# Уточняющие члены предложения

Tags: запятая

Здравствуйте.

*"Справа от дома Есениных, (где именно?) за сельской площадью, среди деревьев виден двухэтажный дом, принадлежавший некогда местной помещице".*

В этом предложении уточняемое будет *"справа от дома Есениных"*, а уточняющее *"за сельской площадью"*? После *"среди деревьев"* запятая не нужна?

Comment: @Dima, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Вы совершенно правы: в этом предложении уточняемое будет "справа от дома Есениных ", а уточняющее "за сельской площадью".